# In a ASP.NET Webforms App - The purpose of Site.Mobile.Master and the ViewSwitcher.ascx control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I normally delete ViewSwitcher.ascx and Site.Mobile.Master from my project whenever I create a new WebApp using the default Webforms template.

After researching I believe the Site.Mobile.Master and ViewSwitcher.ascx are used along with the new Friendly Urls feature.

I am looking for some information on why Microsoft added these files to the default webforms template and how/when I would go about using them. I usually create web applications that run on both desktop and mobile using the same master page.

It seems like a scenario when I would want to use Site.Mobile.Master is when I want to completely separate mobile from desktop. Meaning I would have 2 files like this:

AboutUsMobile.aspx (uses Site.Mobile.Master)
AboutUs.aspx (uses Site.Master)

I believe the ViewSwitcher control simply allows the user to leave mobile and switch to the desktop page.

However, I do not understand what logic is in place to automatically take the user to the Mobile page vs the Desktop page.

I just feel like I don't see the full potential in using these controls and how they work with the new URL routing. Any information on these items would be great.

Comment: So, you can understand why you would want 2 different forms, but not 2 different master pages?